# I want to embark on a Linux From Scratch(LFS)project

Tags: 14.04

Can I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for Linux From Scratch(LFS)?

Comment: [This reply](http://lists.linuxfromscratch.org/pipermail/lfs-support/2014-November/048182.html) from Bruce on the LFS mailing list seems to indicate that it is possible... but I don't know enough to help you further. You might have more luck on the LFS mailing list than here

Comment: If you are talking about building an LFS system using your Ubuntu workstation as a base; then, yes, it is possible. Personally, I have done this on both 12.04 and 14.04. It's a good learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

The host requirements for LFS (Linux From Scratch) are listed at the link below and the page includes a script to check you have everything required.

http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/hostreqs.html

While I have not tried this with Ubuntu, I do not believe you would have any issues.

Note: **you are only using the host system for the beginning compiling and it would not ultimately matter which version of Linux you use.**

http://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/stages.html